# Hash Function which allows for comparison of input without knowing input

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, hash-function

I need to find functions **F** and **F_Verification** such that:

- **F**(*Input1*, *RandomSeed1*) = *Output1*
- **F**(*Input1*, *RandomSeed2*) = *Output2*
- **F_Verification** (*Output1*, *Output2*) = *TRUE*

Cryptographic requirements:

1. Given *Output1* and *Output2*, you must not be able to find input.
2. F may be a surjective function yielding the same output ~1/Billion~ times. It would be best to have some flexibility in how often it is surjective.
3. **F_Verification** May yeild a false positive *again* *~1/Billion~ times with some flexibility*

Extra Details

1. **1. All Inputs will be unique**
2. **F_Verification** must be a quick function
3. Ideally **F** is a slow function

Any suggestions on starting places would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Because when using different RandomSeeds you will get different Outputs. This is the challenge of the program. Can we verify Output1 and Output2 used the same Input given different RandomSeeds without knowing the input, only knowing the encrypted outputs.

Comment: A typical hash function is not injective (meaning multiple inputs are mapped to the same hash value). What are your requirements regarding those? Do they have to be distinguished, or are you fine with `F_Verification` being an over-approximation, in the sense that if it reports false, then the inputs were definitely not equal, but if it reports true, the inputs may or may not have been equal?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of [zero knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) concepts.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 I have made some eddits. Please let me know if more specification would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're going to have a hard time finding a function that does this, because the output of most cryptographic functions is designed to be indistinguishable from random.  Therefore, it's unlikely that you're going to find a function that both produces two identical outputs based on a random seed and lets you recover any information about the input value without knowing the seed.

However, there are some constructions that you can use.  If the two outputs can be the exact same output, then you can just skip the random seed and let F be a secure hash function, like SHA-256 or BLAKE2b.  Then the verification is an equality comparison.  This is the ideal situation that hash functions are designed for, and it's what I recommend unless you know you need different behavior.

If you need to have two different outputs, you can make F this:

```
F(input, seed) = SHA-256(input) || HMAC-SHA-256(seed, input)
```

This still reveals that your objects are the same, but it provides different output on a different seed.  The verification is an equality comparison of the first 32 bytes.

Beyond that, you're looking at situations where your verification isn't cheap.  You can use RSA-PSS to sign the objects, and the salt you use in the signature will make the two signatures different even if the input (which you will have then hashed) is the same.  But RSA verification isn't super cheap as far as cryptographic functions go, although there are worse options.

Pretty much all the other operations involve knowing the seed in order to compare, and you haven't provided that as an option.  If it is, you could use a 256-bit seed and make F into this:

```
F(input, seed) = AES-Key-Wrap(seed, SHA-256(input))
```